# Disabling controls when showing loading bar in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm developping a webapp using AngularJS. I would like to show a load bar when the load of the data from the server takes very long.

To simulate a huge load of data I use $timeout, and I show the loadbar when the operation starts and I hide it when the operation ends.

The problem I'm facing is that, of course I'm only displaying a animated image when the operation starts, so all the controls (button,links, etc) are still available to click during the load of the data. I would like to find a way to disable all the controls during the load process to avoid the user to click on them.

Could you please help me here? Thank you very much in advance!

Some of my code if it helps:

My controls in html:

```
<div class="header">
            <ul id="headerLinks" class="nav nav-pills pull-right">
                <li ng-class="menuItems.home.selected && 'active'"><a   ng-click="changeRootPath('home')">Home</a></li>
                <li ng-class="menuItems.products.selected && 'active'"><a   ng-click="changeRootPath('products')">Products</a></li>
                <li ng-class="menuItems.register.selected && 'active'"><a  ng-click="changeRootPath('register')">Sign in</a></li>
                <li ng-class="menuItems.login.selected && 'active'"><a  ng-controller="LoginController"  ng-click="changeRootPath('login');open('md')" >Login</a></li>
                <li ng-class="menuItems.contact.selected && 'active'"><a  ng-click="changeRootPath('contact')">Contact</a></li>


            </ul>
            <h3 class="text-muted">Arena Club</h3>

</div>
```

The functions to show/hide the loading bar:

```
$scope.showLoader=function()
{
    $scope.loader.loading=true;
}

$scope.hideLoader=function()
{
    $scope.loader.loading=false;
}
```

And the controller attached to the view:

```
app.controller('ProductsController', ['$scope','productsFactory','commonFactory','productsFactoryHelper','$timeout',function ($scope,productsFactory,commonFactory,productsFactoryHelper,$timeout) 
                               {

var _init=function()
{
//loadAllProducts();

$scope.showLoader();
$timeout(loadAllProducts, 6000);
}


var loadAllProducts=function()
{

    productsFactory.query(function(response)
        {
        $scope.products=response;
        $scope.hideLoader();
        },function(error)
        {
            commonFactory.Pop('error','Ups! The products are not available at this moment. Please try again later. If the problem persists contact a system administrator');
        });

}   

_init();    
                               }]);
```

Comment: Could you post your html. If its form controls then you can use `ng-disabled="loader.loading"` to your form inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing what your controls look like or how they are set up, here are some ideas:

- If they are an HTML form, you can use `disabled` attribute on your inputs. With angular, you could do `ng-disabled='loader.loading'`.
- You could put your entire loading screen in an overlay or just a div over the controls, with a higher `z-index` to keep the items below it from being clickable. If outside of the loader, you could still conditionally show it using the same flag as the loader.
- You could have the controls hide/remove themselves using the `ngHide` or `ngIf` directives.

Comment: Thanks! As my controls are links the attribute ng-disabled does not work here. I like the second option, how can I do in html to set the loading image in a overlay, so the controls are in the background and therefore they are not clickable?

Comment: As @idotpdot described, you can use a div, which will contain your loading image. Also use a high z-index in css so all your components will be like disabled.

Comment: Hey @fgonzalez, here's a [demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MikeGertrudes/1Lncn9xs/1/) showing how to do this easily.

Comment: Wow! Thank you very mucho  @idotpdot, that's all i needed, it works great. Thanks!